# VSTO Add-ins and comctl32.dll

Tags: vsto, comctl32

I'm developing Word and Excel 2010 add-ins using VSTO 4.0 and .NET 4.0. This add-ins integrate some features of our thick client, which is written in MFC. And MFC dialogs using Win2k styles when I call they from add-ins (in a thick client they look normal). In the list of loaded libraries there are two versions of comctl32.dll: 5.82 and 6.10. How can I get Word and Excel to use the correct version of comctl32.dll? I tried to modify the manifest Excel - it helps, but this method does not suit me.